# What's the difference between PTVS and IronPython Tools for Visual Studio?

Tags: python, ptvs

what is the difference between Python Tools for Visual Studio and the IronPython Tools for Visual Studio included in the IronPython distribution? If there is a difference can they live side by side?

Answer (score 3):

They are two different things.

Python Tools for Visual Studio is an extension for Visual Studio for a Python IDE, but for vanilla python using a python compiler/virtual machine. It is not a compiler in itself, just an IDE.

IronPython is a separate compiler for Python whereby Python is compiled to the .NET Platform to run on the CLR. The IronPython Tools for Visual Studio integrate that compiler into Visual Studio.

Edit (from comment below):
IronPython and PTVS work fine together and can be installed on the same machine.

Comment: I am not aware if they can or can not live SxS.

Comment: ooh... thanks... i thought PTVS is update version of IronPython

Comment: @vcsjones They can live side by side. I currently have PTVS and IronPython installed and it works without issue.

Comment: @user3752226 Great. Feel free to edit the answer to include that.